# How do I check two textboxes for two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

One has txtDateReceived and second has txtVendorPackDate. Before insert will add record I have to check if txtDateReceived is not erlier then txtVendorPackDate. I try use TextChanged event.

```
protected void txtVendorPackDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime toDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
    bool parseResultMin = DateTime.TryParse(txtVendorPackDate.Text, out fromDate);
    bool parseResultMax = DateTime.TryParse(txtDateReceived.Text, out toDate);
    if (toDate < fromDate)
    {
        txtVendorPackDate.Text = "";
        lblDateExpired.Visible = true;
        lblDateExpired.Text = "Selected date is incorrect, please enter correct data.";
        txtVendorFatPerc.Focus();
    }

    double expired = toDate.Subtract(fromDate).TotalDays;

    if (expired >= 60)
    {

        lblDateExpired.Text = "Date Expired " + expired + " days after pack day!!!" 
        lblDateExpired.Visible = true;
    }  
}
```

How I could do it from client side not using controls validation.

Comment: Thanks Grant you are right I don't need min and max values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (!parseResultMin || !parseResultMax || toDate < fromDate)
```

In your code, if both dates are invalid, `toDate` and `fromDate` will both be `DateTime.MinValue`, so the expression `toDate < fromDate` won't be true.

Comment: Thanks, comecme. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CompareValidator control to check that the vendor pack date is less than the received date.  If both fields are required, you can also use the RequiredFieldValidator.  I would employ a combination of RequiredFieldValidators and CompareValidators.

One RequiredFieldValidator for each textbox to make sure the user enters a value.
One CompareValidator for each textbox to make sure the value entered is a date type.
One CompareValidator to make sure the vendor pack date is earlier than the received date.

Comment: I can't use this solutin b/c I also have gridview where I am allowing for update rows. When I do comparation from control It won't update gridview control.